# Exporting or Viewing Apple Watch heart rate info

Tags: apple-watch, health-kit

I have found the corresponding Activity app on the iPhone, which shows exercise history, but is there a way you can see the history of each heart rate measurement in bpm? Maybe through a HealthKit application?

---

EDIT: Thanks to bmike's suggestion, I found the export function of the **Health** app on the iPhone. The button in the upper right lets you send the raw data as an XML file.

[image: Health App Screenshot]

Comment: Beroe that's great news.  Could you post an example of the XML or the raw data as I can't find an example on line.  Thanks!  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple allows you to inspect all data using the Health app itself. In addition to the graphs it prepares, you can tap the graph and then **Show All Data**

As you know, there's no export function on iOS itself, but there's no reason any third party app can't request access to that data (which you also can see and approve from the **Share Data** tab of that app.

I would check out apps like:

- https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/heart-rate-variability-logger/id683984776?mt=8

Answer (score 4):

On the main screen for health data there is an icon in the upper right (mine is a red silhouette of a person). If you press this icon the next screen gives an option to export data. It is easy to import data into Excel as an XML file. From there you can use normal Excel commands to filter, create charts etc.....

Comment: This generates 22 bytes of data (after a long time) in a zip file that can't be unzipped in Finder and results in "warning [export.zip]:  zipfile is empty" in response to `unzip`. [Is there a way to actually do this and get data?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/307761/4395)