# How do I export Apple Health data?

Tags: archive, health.app, health-kit

Though there are are some [old answers here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/183159/4395) about how this was once accomplished, it's not clear what the current procedure for exporting Apple Health data is, and though there [is indeed an export option](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/296591/4395) in the Health app, this generates an empty file (after taking about 5 minutes).

How do I export Apple Health data?

Comment: Just tried the export option you linked to above. For me it generated a 3.4MB ZIP file that contains a 3.6MB export_cda.xml file and a 74 MB export.xml file. Both are full of data. How did you transfer the ZIP file from your iOS device to your Mac? Perhaps the file was corrupted or interrupted during transfer?

Comment: @AlistairMcMillan By mail attachment. I’ll try saving as a file.

Comment: AirDrop between devices worked for me.

Comment: @AlistairMcMillan: No luck. 22KB and unopenable everywhere, regardless of how it's shared. Is this accessible in iCloud perhaps in a form I can backup to use in standard formats? Perhaps there's a third party app that reads all health data and is able to save it?